# El Capitan Ruby binaries installation issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, homebrew, rake-test

Just trying to get through some parts of the Hartl rails tutorial to familiarize myself with the rails framework. I have homebrew installed (removed and reinstalled it because it giving me trouble after using El Capitan), and got a fresh version of rvm with `rvm get stable`

I went into the directory containing the project, and I got this message

```
ruby-2.3.0-dev is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-2.3.0-dev'
```

Previously, I'd tried using 2.3.0 as the latest version (it was the newest thing showing up when I ran `rvm list`, not sure why), but now I want to change that to 2.3.1. Anybody know how I can change the ruby version for this project?

Additionally, when I run `rvm install ruby-2.3.1` , I get this error

```
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.11/x86_64/ruby-2.3.1.
```

This led me to trying to reinstall homebrew, update my version of rvm, etc. I tried all of that and am still getting this error message.

The whole reason this happened is because I tried executing a test with

```
$ bundle exec rake test
```

I got this message

```
RubyDep: WARNING: Your Ruby is outdated/buggy. (To disable warnings, set RUBY_DEP_GEM_SILENCE_WARNINGS=1)
RubyDep: WARNING: Your Ruby is: 2.3.0 (buggy). Recommendation: install 2.3.1.
```

Haven't been able to install 2.3.1 and I'm just losing my mind here.

edit - Does one recommend installing directly from source instead of using binaries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reproduced your steps in my Mac laptop running OS X El Capitan. Executing the command `rvm install 2.3.1` I got the same error as you, but after that rvm kept on executing the command and eventually downloaded and installed the binaries of Ruby 2.3.1. My output was like this:

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.11/x86_64/ruby-2.3.1.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' are already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.3.1 - #downloading ruby-2.3.1, this may take a while depending on your connection...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 13.7M  100 13.7M    0     0  5854k      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:-- 5855k
No checksum for downloaded archive, recording checksum in user configuration.
ruby-2.3.1 - #extracting ruby-2.3.1 to /Users/user/.rvm/src/ruby-2.3.1....
ruby-2.3.1 - #configuring...........................................................
ruby-2.3.1 - #post-configuration.
ruby-2.3.1 - #compiling.............................................................
ruby-2.3.1 - #installing.........
ruby-2.3.1 - #making binaries executable..
Installed rubygems 2.5.1 is newer than 2.4.8 provided with installed ruby, skipping installation, use --force to force installation.
ruby-2.3.1 - #gemset created /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global
ruby-2.3.1 - #importing gemset /Users/user/.rvm/gemsets/global.gems...............................................
ruby-2.3.1 - #generating global wrappers........
ruby-2.3.1 - #gemset created /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1
ruby-2.3.1 - #importing gemsetfile /Users/user/.rvm/gemsets/default.gems evaluated to empty gem list
ruby-2.3.1 - #generating default wrappers........
ruby-2.3.1 - #adjusting #shebangs for (gem irb erb ri rdoc testrb rake).
Install of ruby-2.3.1 - #complete
Ruby was built without documentation, to build it run: rvm docs generate-ri
```

After that I executed `rvm use 2.3.1` and `ruby -v` and the output of the last command was:

```
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin15]
```

So I could successfully install Ruby 2.3.1 on Mac OS X El Capitan. Please provide further information if this cannot help solving your problem.

Comment: My issue was that I didn't through the whole output message. I saw the prompt to read "rvm help mount" and checked that out. I was totally lost, and then I came here...now successfully running ruby 2.3.1 on my machine.

Comment: Same here. rvm could benefit from some UX :-)